# How to update job node number in Slurm?

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I have a pending job and I want to resize it.
I tried:

```
scontrol update job <jobid> NumNodes=128
```

It does not work.

Note: I can change the walltime using `scontrol`. But when I try to change number of nodes, it failed. It looks like I can change the nodes according to this page http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/cori/running-jobs/monitoring-jobs/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution I got from NERSC help desk (Credits to Woo-Sun Yang at LBNL):

`$ scontrol update jobid=jobid numnodes=new_numnodes-new_numnodes`

E.g. `$ scontrol update jobid=12345 numnodes=10-10`

The trick is to have numnodes in the above format. It works for both shrinking and expanding your nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You can resize jobs in Slurm provided that the job is pending or running.

According to the [FAQ](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#job_size), you can resize following the next steps (with examples):

### Expand

1. Assuming that **j1** requests 4 nodes and is submitted with:

   ```
   $ salloc -N4 bash
   ```
2. Submit a new job (**j2**) with the number of extra nodes for **j1** (in this case 10 for a total of 14 nodes) and make it dependent of **j1** (SLURM_JOBID):

   ```
   $ salloc -N10 --dependency=expand:$SLURM_JOBID
   ```
3. Deallocate the nodes of **j2**:

   ```
   $ scontrol update jobid=$SLURM_JOBID NumNodes=0
   ```
4. Terminate **j2**:

   ```
   $ exit
   ```
5. Assign to **j1** the previous released nodes:

   ```
   $ scontrol update jobid=$SLURM_JOBID NumNodes=ALL
   ```
6. And update the environmental variables of **j1**:

   ```
   $ ./slurm_job_$SLURM_JOBID_resize.sh
   ```

Now, **j1** has 14 nodes.

### Shrink

1. Assuming that **j1** has been submitted with:

   ```
   $ salloc -N4 bash
   ```
2. Update **j1** to the new size:

   ```
   $ scontrol update jobid=$SLURM_JOBID NumNodes=2
   $ scontrol update jobid=$SLURM_JOBID NumNodes=ALL
   ```
3. And update the environmental variables of **j1** (the script is created by the previous commands):

   ```
   $ ./slurm_job_$SLURM_JOBID_resize.sh
   ```

Now, **j1** has 2 nodes.

Comment: What if I submitted my job using `srun`, can I still change the size of the job?

Comment: If you submitted through `srun`, wouldn't your job already be running?