# SLURM releasing resources using scontrol update results in unknown endtime

Tags: batch-processing, slurm

I have a program that will dynamically release resources during job execution, using the command:

scontrol update JobId=$SLURM_JOB_ID NodeList=${remaininghosts}

However, this results in some very weird behavior sometimes. Where the job is re-queued. Below is the output of sacct

sacct -j 1448590

JobID   NNodes State  Start  End   NodeList

---

1448590   4 RESIZING  20:47:28 01:04:22 [0812,0827],[0663-0664]

1448590.0 4 COMPLETED 20:47:30 20:47:30 [0812,0827],[0663-0664]

1448590.1 4 RESIZING  20:47:30 01:04:22 [0812,0827],[0663-0664]

1448590   3 RESIZING  01:04:22 01:06:42 [0812,0827],0663

1448590   2 RESIZING  01:06:42 1:12:42  0827,tnxt-0663

1448590   4 COMPLETED 05:33:15 Unknown  0805-0807,0809]

The first lines show everything works fine, nodes are getting released but in the last line, it shows a completely different set of nodes with an unknown end time. The slurm logs show the job got requeued:

requeue JobID=1448590 State=0x8000 NodeCnt=1 due to node failure.

I suspect this might happen because the head node is killed, but the slurm documentation doesn't say anything about that.

Does anybody had an idea or suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398201/how-to-update-job-node-number-in-slurm/49403514#49403514) there was a discussion about resizing jobs.

In your particular case, for shrinking I would use:

1. Assuming that **j1** has been submitted with:

   ```
   $ salloc -N4 bash
   ```
2. Update **j1** to the new size:

   ```
   $ scontrol update jobid=$SLURM_JOBID NumNodes=2
   $ scontrol update jobid=$SLURM_JOBID NumNodes=ALL
   ```
3. And update the environmental variables of **j1** (the script is created by the previous commands):

   ```
   $ ./slurm_job_$SLURM_JOBID_resize.sh
   ```

Now, **j1** has 2 nodes.

In your example, your "remaininghost" list, as you say, may exclude the head node that is needed by Slurm to shrink the job. If you provide a quantity instead of a list, the resize should work.